# trouble connecting a linux server to a windows client

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, samba, dns

How can I connect a Linux server to a Windows client. I've both operating systems already installed on VirtualBox — Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Windows 10 Enterprise. For the Linux server, I kept the default VM ipv4 configurations, like so:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.2.255
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
```

I've also utilized a samba primary domain controller and have the following `resolv.conf` file:

```
# Samba server IP address
nameserver 10.0.2.15

# fallback resolver
nameserver 9.9.9.9

# main domain for Samba
search cn.lan
```

Tried pinging the domain and stuff and it works as expected. Then I assigned the ipv4 address to the windows client:

```
IP assignment:                Manual
IPv4 address:                 10.0.2.14
IPv4 subnet prefix length:    24
IPv4 gateway:                 10.0.2.15
IPv4 DNS servers:             10.0.2.15
                              9.9.9.9
```

I've set the DNS server's IP address with the Linux server's. Now the problem comes when I try to ping my Linux domain, which is `dc1.cn.lan`. This is what appears in the Windows terminal:

```
> ping dc1.cn.lan
Ping request could not find host dc1.cn.lan. Please check the name and try again.
```

I already tried searching for fixes but this problem still persists. I suspect that the issue is with the Windows client's subnetting, which is a skill that I'm not ashamed to admit that I particularly suck at. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!